# velocity.js reset svg animation

Tags: svg, velocity.js

I'm using velocity.js (1.2.1) to create a fairly complex multi-step svg animation. I want users to be able to reset the animation at the end and run it again - by reset I mean if several elements have moved and had opacity changed they will all go back to their original starting positions and opacity, this can be instant, no need to play the animations in reverse. I want to create reusable code that can apply to multiple different svg animations.

There doesn't seem to be a way to rewind UI pack sequences. Other solutions I could think of:

- Record the original attributes in a lookup object for each element then loop through and reset each element - I suspect this could be slow.
- Clone the SVG, remove the original at the end and append the clone - this results in duplicate ID references in IE and the SVG turns black as a result

I tried the following solutions to cloning:

```
$(document).data("initialSVG", $("#svg1").clone(true));
// animate... then reset
$(document).data("initialSVG").replaceAll("#svg1");
```

Also:

```
var clonedSVG = $("#svg1").clone();
// animate... then reset
$("#svg1").remove();
$(".container").append(clonedSVG);
```

Both resulted in black svgs in IE.

Does anyone have an improvement on these approaches or an alternative suggestion using velocity.js please?

Comment: What do you mean by "rewind"? Play the whole animation back in reverse to the initial state? Or simply reset it?

Comment: I meant reset to original state without any animation. I've edited the question to hopefully clarify.